# How to position a "right-aligned" text also in the center without relative position?

Tags: equations, positioning, alignment

This is what I would like to achieve, a formula that is right-aligned, but at the same time positioned at the center of the page, without any relative position but just automatically right and center aligned... is this possible? With relative positions I can, of course, position it wherever I want
[image: Correct right and center text positioning image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `\align` environment from the `amsmath` package.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align*}
    (z_1-z_2)/(e_1-e_2)\; mod\; q&\\
    =((se_1+r)-(se_2+r))/(e_1-e_2)\; mod\; q&\\
    =s(e_1-e_2)/(e_1-e_2)\; mod\; q&\\
    =s&\\
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And thanks for correcting the parenthesis mistake, I didn't notice! hahah, you've been super helpful, thanks again.